# Input helper ember reverse disabled state

Tags: ember.js

I want to disable an inputfield if a property is false or does not exist. To do this, you should need a reverse binding for the input helper, something like (pseudo code):

```
{{ input ... disabled=!isNew}}
```

After reading the [docs](http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/input-helpers/), I could find nothing about reverse boolean structure.

Should I solve this by using a computed property*, or is there a better way?

---

*
Something like:

```
loginFieldDisabled: function() {
    return ! this.get('isNew');
}.property('isNew')
```

Comment: By the way, personally, I think your question was very good. It shows that you at least attempted to read the docs, you proposed a possible solution and you worded it clearly and concisely. That seems to be very rare on SO these days, so give yourself a pat on the back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can think of two ways that I would do it. First, use a conditional block:

```
{{#if isNew}}
    {{input}}
{{else}}
    {{input disabled}}
{{/if}}
```

But that comes with its own set of issues, since it adds and removes the text field from the DOM. The other way would be to modify `Ember.TextField`. Here's something that would work (tested in a JSBin):

```
Ember.TextField.reopen({
    notDisabled: function(key, value) {
        if (arguments.length > 1) {
            this.set('disabled', !value);
        }

        return !this.get('disabled');
    }.property('disabled')
});
```

Then, in your template:

```
{{input notDisabled=isNew}}
```

The second one is probably what you want. You could also extend `Ember.TextField` instead of modifying it.

Answer (score 6):

For those who came to question by googling, currently you could use the [Ember Truth helpers](https://github.com/jmurphyau/ember-truth-helpers) to achieve a solution for this problem:

```
{{input ... disabled=(not isNew)}}
```